# How to undo PATH changes? (CentOS)

Tags: linux, path, console

Exporting PATH I carelessly copy/pasted path with new line, so instead of

```
export PATH=/usr/local/something:$PATH
```

I got just

```
export PATH=/usr/local/something{\n}
```

So I guess all my usefull PATH entries got erased. How do I undo the changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you did that in a terminal, just exit the terminal and start another one.

Changes made to the environment in a specific process are only *within* that process, so starting a new one will get you back your path as it's created with the various startup files.

If you've changed it *in* the startup files, just go get them from backups, although you'll probably find you can just comment out, or fix, the offending line since it just prefixed the current path with one directory anyway.

Comment: Could you explain to me though, if changes are only within that process, how come the new ones I added to PATH remain even after closing the terminal?